# Grayscale image so that the red text could not be differentiated

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I have this screen capture and I want to edit this with photoshop or any other software you recommend:

[image]

As you see there are two red colored texts and the remaining of the text is just normal black.

I want to change the entire content of the image to shades of back color I mean I want to grayscale the image so that the red text couldn't be recognizable.

To achieve this I used Snagit to grayscale the image but I get this result:

[image]

As you see we can still differentiate the red text. And that's not we wanted. we want to change the red color to be just like the other part of the text.

Note: the issue is the red color can change a bit because I will capture this image with Snagit.

Note 2: the solution should be simple and with a few steps because I have lots of these images and defiantly we prefer a a simple procedure.

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense with the images deleted.

Comment: Yes, why are the images removed? Can someone roll the edit back, or, if the OP wants them censored for some reason, delete the post?

Comment: @Joachim - any high rep user can roll it back, but [even though the same data is visible in the answers, though I have no clue what it says] the OP *may* have a specific reason for doing so… or it might just be an accident. Personally, I'd prefer clarification from the OP before unilaterally reversing their decision.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with photography.

Comment: @scottbb This does have application to photography, though. Remember using green filters when doing B&W film photography to reduce the brightness of red objects in the image? It's pretty much the same concept when we use a green filter in digital image processing to attenuate the brightness of red objects captured by Bayer masked sensors. Whether it's a screen shot or a photo one took, the way to match the black text to the red text when converting to grey scale is exactly the same.

Comment: @MichaelC Graphic design, digital signal processing, and photography sometimes all have overlapping solutions, sure. But the question and application weren't about photography. This probably should have been a [graphicdesign.se] or possibly (but probably not) a [su] question. But it was answered and accepted before it was flagged for migration. If you want to nominate it for reopening, please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many images you want something that can be automated. [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) is a free toolbox designed to perform many image operations in shell scripts (.BAT, if you are on Windows). In the case at hand:

```
convert WithRed.png -colorspace Gray WithoutRed.png
```

gives:

[image]

You can even increase sharpness:

```
convert WithRed.png -colorspace Gray -sharpen 0x1.0 WithoutRed.png
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant ... I'll try this and come back to you...

Answer (score 2):

<sup>In anticipation of this being migrated to Graphic Design</sup>

Image menu/Adjustments/Black & White.
Then just pull the reds back slightly.

[image]